# HTML5 right click video options hidden behind a wrapping div

Tags: html, html5-video

Like the title suggests, I've got a HTML5 video that is currently sitting behind a wrapping div, like so:

```
<div class="video-wrap">
                <video poster="/Media/video/index.files/html5video/Circles_Sequence_MORE_TEXT_v05.jpg" style="width:100%" title="What is  Customer Devotion?" id="html5_video_qlpjkwou10fcg14i">
                    <source src="/Media/video/index.files/html5video/Circles_Sequence_MORE_TEXT_v05.m4v" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="/Media/video/index.files/html5video/Circles_Sequence_MORE_TEXT_v05.webm" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="/Media/video/index.files/html5video/Circles_Sequence_MORE_TEXT_v05.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                    <source src="/Media/video/index.files/html5video/Circles_Sequence_MORE_TEXT_v05.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                </video>
            </div>
```

The issue is that when the video plays, because of the constrictive div, there's no way to get any of the native right click controls up. I.e. I can't pause, play, loop, etc.

Is there a way around this without removing the div?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

controls ="" attribute need to be added in video tag.

Example

```
    <video width="400" controls>
```

[demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)

Comment: I may not have been clear enough - what I'm looking for is the ability to display video controls on **right-click**


The client doesn't want the video controls to display, nor will they with the parameters chosen.

The problem is that the way the current HTML is laid out; any right clicks don't directly interact with the video screen. It seems that, on first looks, the only way for me to do this is to remove the div class="video-wrap", which I don't want to do as it'll involve a lot more layout changes..

Answer (score 0):

A nice workaround could be to popup the video. That way the user could interact directly with the video instead of the div.